# Redirect my old links to new ones

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I rewrite the url of my site via my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /views/sessions/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blogs/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /views/blogs/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^groups/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /views/groups/$1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^events/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ /views/events/reports_$1.php [L]
```

This works, when we type the url `mysite.com/blogs/index/` we get to `mysite.com/views/blogs/index.php`

Now I would like that when you type `mysite.com/views/account/datas.php` the user is redirected to `mysite.com/account/datas/` or displays an error 404 not found

On another post I was told to do that :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/sessions/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ views/sessions/$1.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&s=old [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&)?s=old$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^views/sessions/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ $1/ [R=302,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/account/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^account/(.*)/$ views/account/$1.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&s=old [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^account/(.*&)?s=old$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^views/account/([a-zA-Z]+).php$ /account/$1/ [R=302,NC,L]

...
```

But I have this error (when I try to access `mysite.com/account/datas/`) :

**Not Found The requested URL /views/sessions/account/datas.php was not found on this server.**

How to do ?